# Property getter calling function can't be binded?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a model class with a property that returns a value by calling a method, but when i try to bind that property, there is result on the page, but also no error occuring.

```
export class TestClass {
  testProperty: string = this.getString();

  getString() {
    return 'hello';
  }
}
```

in html:

```
{{model.testProperty}}
```

Does Typescript / Angular not support this? What is the common way to do it?

Comment: Works fine for me. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxmccr)

Answer (score 0):

```
public get testProperty(): string {
   return 'hello'
}
```

If you use the 'get' after the public, it allow the function to be called as it would be a normal variable. I think you shouldnt even need the 'model.'

Comment: Can you add some more explanation to that code such that others can learn from it?

Comment: Yes, done, sorry. I replied this one on the train :P

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple enough class. What you could do is initialize testProperty as null or by a default value and in ngOnInit() assign the returned value from the function.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class TestClass implements OnInit {

  testProperty: string = null;

  ngOnInut() {
     this.testProperty = this.getString();
  }

  getString() {
    return 'hello';
  }
}
```

The ngOnInit() is a lifecycle hooks and runs when the component is initialized.